# remove /?no_cache=1 in URL using Typo3 6.2 and RealURL extension

Tags: typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, realurl

There is a page that has the no_cache option activated but realURL shows this: 
"www.domain.com/path/to/page/?no_cache=1"

and I'd like it to just be: 
"www.domain.com/path/to/page".

Is there a simple way to achieving this? I don't want to show whether the page is cached or not in the URL.

At the moment I'm using the "news" extension but I will replace it with my own and in either case this page will have the no_cache option enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the no_cache option instead run the extension as USER_INT.

With tt_news this should work:

```
plugin.tt_news = USER_INT
```

With your custom extension you have got full control about USER vs. USER_INT anyway.